# mysql trigger not working with if statement

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateNewEmp
AFTER UPDATE ON BasicDetails
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN
    if(NEW.MiddleName<>OLD.MiddleName) then
      insert into BasicDetails_audit(MiddleName,`State`,Country,Community) 
      VALUES(NEW.MiddleName,NEW.`State`,NEW.Country,NEW.Community)
end if;
end
```

It throws a syntax error near the `END IF` statement. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Semicolon after INSERT query is lost. PS. Rewrite the query and move the condition from IF to WHERE clause of INSERT query. PPS. Your data saved by a trigger do not allow to distinguish what record was altered...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372872/mysql-trigger-if-condition-exists

Answer (score -1):

You have to change DELIMITER to something else than `;`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateNewEmp AFTER UPDATE ON BasicDetails FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
  IF(NEW.MiddleName<>OLD.MiddleName) 
  THEN
    INSERT INTO BasicDetails_audit(MiddleName,`State`,Country,Community) 
         VALUES (NEW.MiddleName,NEW.`State`,NEW.Country,NEW.Community);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: And missing some semicolons.